# How can `:i` show a different type than `:t`?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When using [random-fu 0.3.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.3.0.0) I get confused exploring the types for `random`.

Checking with `:t` I get

```hs
ghci> :t Data.Random.sample
Data.Random.sample
  :: (Data.Random.Distribution d t, Data.Random.StatefulGen g m,
      Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader g m) =>
     d t -> m t
```

But `:i` shows a different type

```hs
ghci> :i Data.Random.sample
Data.Random.sample ::
  (Data.Random.Sampleable d m t, Data.Random.StatefulGen g m,
   Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader g m) =>
  d t -> m t
        -- Defined in `Data.Random.Sample'
```

The [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.3.0.0/docs/src/Data.Random.Sample.html#sample) seems to require the `Sampleable` constrain. Interestingly, there is a comment that asks for `Distribution` instead.

```hs
-- |Sample a random variable using the default source of entropy for the
-- monad in which the sampling occurs.
sample :: (Sampleable d m t, StatefulGen g m, MonadReader g m) => d t -> m t
sample thing = ask >>= \gen -> sampleFrom gen thing

-- |Sample a random variable in a \"functional\" style.  Typical instantiations
-- of @s@ are @System.Random.StdGen@ or @System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64.PureMT@.
-- sample :: (Distribution d a, StatefulGen g m, MonadReader g m) => d t -> m t
-- sample thing gen = runStateGen gen (\stateGen -> sampleFrom stateGen thing)
```

What is causing the difference between the types reported by `:i` and `:t`?

(I am not asking about how to use `random-fu`, there are [examples that work in their github](https://github.com/haskell-numerics/random-fu/issues/90))

Comment: It looks like there is an `instance Distribution d t => Sampleable d m t`, so the constraint gets simplified immediately with `:t`, while `:i` sticks to the type used at declaration time. Note that `:t` takes an expression, not just an identifier name, so it does perform more steps (type inference, constraint resolution, etc.). Moreover, that instance is overlapping and the module uses incoherent instances, which can be (IMO just are) evil. Probably you need to turn a few extension on (overlapping&incoherent instances) to avoid the unwanted simplification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a similar example of the same phenomenon with more familiar constraints:

```
> f :: (Eq a, Ord a) => a -> Bool; f x = x > x
> :i f
f :: forall a. (Ord a, Eq a) => a -> Bool
> :t f
f :: forall {a}. Ord a => a -> Bool
```

GHC has noticed that the `Eq` constraint isn't needed in the type, because the `Ord` constraint already guarantees it<sup>*</sup>:

```
> :i Ord
class Eq a => Ord a where
<snip>
```

Your situation is similar, just with a more complicated class. Stated explicitly: `:i` gives information about the definition as written by the programmer, parroting back exactly what was written as the type signature (and so only works on lone identifiers), while `:t` works on any expression but runs a full type inference algorithm, including constraint simplification.

<sup>*</sup> You might wonder whether it noticed that `==` wasn't used, and this is the real reason that the `Eq` constraint isn't needed. But no; change the definition to `f x = x > x || x == x` and the `Eq` constraint will still be omitted from `:t f`.